# ImageView for many pictures on iOS

Tags: ios, layout, imageview

I want to design a layout like the following in iOS:
[image]

What is the best way to design it? Total images in view is from 1 to 5. If it is 1 pic, can stretch that pic to imageView size. If > 1 pic, I need to divide imageView to show each pic in smaller sizes.

Comment: you can try collectionView, depending on your images.count you can arrange the layout.

Comment: You can achieve this using Pinterest View.

Answer (score 0):

As you have small amount of the cases, i would recommend to do the layout manually and describe all 5 cases in code.

So you just will have 5 imageViews and will position them in any way you want, depending on the number of the images available.